# Pass radio buttons with the same name to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a form with a button that will dynamically add a group of inputs of the same form.

I already managed to get it done, except for one issue.

I couldn't pass the parameters from radio input type with the same name to the servlet for everytime I add the fields. It only passed the value to servlet once. Weird thing is I could pass the text input type successfully.

Or is there any other way to pass the value from the radio button to the servlet?

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 2;

$("#addDynamicDivs").click(function () {
var newTextBoxDiv1 = $(document.createElement('div'))
 .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv1');
 newTextBoxDiv1.attr("style",'float: left;');

 var newTextBoxDiv2 = $(document.createElement('div'))
 .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv2');
 newTextBoxDiv2.attr("style",'float: left;');

 var newTextBoxDiv3 = $(document.createElement('div'))
 .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv3');
 newTextBoxDiv3.attr("style",'float: left;');

 var newTextBoxDiv4 = $(document.createElement('div'))
 .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv4');
 newTextBoxDiv4.attr("style",'float: left;');

 newTextBoxDiv1.after().html('<label>Speaker Name : </label>' +
  '<input type="text" name="speakername" id="speakername" value="" >');

  newTextBoxDiv2.after().html('<label>Speaker Country : </label>' +
  '<input type="text" name="speakercountry" id="speakercountry" value="" >');

  newTextBoxDiv3.after().html('<label>Speaker Company : </label>' +
  '<input type="text" name="speakercompany" id="speakercompany" value="" >');

  newTextBoxDiv4.after().html('<label>ID Type: </label>' +
  '<ul name="idtype class="forms-list">'+
  '<li><input type="radio" name="idtype" id="idtype" value="New ID">'+
  '<label for="New ID">New ID</label></li>'+
  '<li><input type="radio" name="idtype" id="idtype" value="Old ID">'+
  '<label for="Old ID">Old ID</label></li></ul>');

  newTextBoxDiv1.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
  newTextBoxDiv2.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
  newTextBoxDiv3.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
  newTextBoxDiv4.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


});
```

});

From the servlet, the parameters are retrieved by this code:

```
String[] speakername    = request.getParameterValues("speakername");
String[] speakercountry = request.getParameterValues("speakercountry");
String[] speakercompany = request.getParameterValues("speakercompany");
String[] idtype         = request.getParameterValues("idtype");
```

I print out the length of each String array above, and I got 2 for each of the parameters except for idtype which the length is 1.

All the dynamic params are already included inside the form.

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons will usually only send one value out of the group with the request. By design, only one radio button can be selected out of the group. If you add more radio buttons with the same name to the form, the browser should still pass only one selected value for the group when you submit the form.

If you want to have multiple of this form passed, you will be best off differentiating between the dynamically added forms (it looks like you want all the data to be sent together, so you'll need to add a unique identifier to the name of each `<input>` element, but otherwise having them in separate `<form>`s would be preferable). I would not recommend relying on the browser passing multiple `<input>`s with the same `name` in the same `<form>`.

Comment: I agree. Another way to do it is to add an index at the end of the field name for each group, e.g. idtype0, idtype1, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Neo Kabuto . Basically those input fields will be added dynamically as many as user want. I renamed the input with other name but it only worked when I add those inputs only once.
Adding the index is a great idea, but how can I do that on dynamically added elements?

Comment: @user3790782 You may just want to go for the simplest solution and have a global variable that keeps track of how many input groups you've added. Then you'll just need to change your code for to insert that value in the end of the `name`s of every `<input>` you add to the document.